# People picker - add new domain - not working at all

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, people-picker

Asked about this before but have some things have changed and I will refine my question
[SharePoint 2016 OnPrem - Peoplepicker from other domain not allow pull of data](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/287232/sharepoint-2016-onprem-peoplepicker-from-other-domain-not-allow-pull-of-data)

I created a new Web application and configured People Picker with the Scripts Trevor recommended

```
$key = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -Force
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::SetApplicationCredentialKey($key)
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://webAppUrl
$adsearchobj = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain
$userpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "UserPassword1" -AsPlainText -Force #Password for the user account CONTOSO\s-useraccount
$adsearchobj.DomainName = "contoso.com"
$adsearchobj.ShortDomainName = "CONTOSO" #Optional
$adsearchobj.IsForest = $true #$true for Forest, $false for Domain
$adsearchobj.LoginName = "s-useraccount"
$adsearchobj.SetPassword($userpassword)

$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Add($adsearchobj)
$wa.Update()
```

Had some issues with the pw to one of the other domains but now that is solved. We have several domains to add. It worked fine.

BUT
When I try to run the same script with 5 domains it doesn't work. If I add one at the time it works fine but when I add the last one, nothing works. Not even the once that worked before. Have tried with two "old" web applications and no success. Only the new Web application
I have some "old" Web applications in my production environment that I need this to work in.
Please let me know if you need more information to help me understand what happens
Thanks

Comment: please, let me ask a silly question: when you execute one script the time, it runs in different context domains, ok? The you run script for all domains, the domain context changes too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run this in a single script, you need to either update and dispose of the current objects or use multiple objects. For example:

```
$key = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -Force
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::SetApplicationCredentialKey($key)
$adsearchobj = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain
$userpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "UserPassword1" -AsPlainText -Force #Password for the user account CONTOSO\s-useraccount
$adsearchobj.DomainName = "contoso.com"
$adsearchobj.ShortDomainName = "CONTOSO" #Optional
$adsearchobj.IsForest = $true #$true for Forest, $false for Domain
$adsearchobj.LoginName = "s-useraccount"
$adsearchobj.SetPassword($userpassword)

$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Add($adsearchobj)

$adsearchobj2 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain
$userpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "UserPassword1" -AsPlainText -Force #Password for the user account CONTOSO\s-useraccount
$adsearchobj2.DomainName = "contoso.com"
$adsearchobj2.ShortDomainName = "CONTOSO" #Optional
$adsearchobj2.IsForest = $true #$true for Forest, $false for Domain
$adsearchobj2.LoginName = "s-useraccount"
$adsearchobj2.SetPassword($userpassword)

$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Add($adsearchobj2)
$wa.Update()
```

Alternatively:

```
$key = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -Force
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::SetApplicationCredentialKey($key)

$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://webAppUrl
$adsearchobj = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain
$userpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "UserPassword1" -AsPlainText -Force #Password for the user account CONTOSO\s-useraccount
$adsearchobj.DomainName = "contoso.com"
$adsearchobj.ShortDomainName = "CONTOSO" #Optional
$adsearchobj.IsForest = $true #$true for Forest, $false for Domain
$adsearchobj.LoginName = "s-useraccount"
$adsearchobj.SetPassword($userpassword)

$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Add($adsearchobj)
$wa.Update()

$adsearchobj = $null

$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://webAppUrl
$adsearchobj = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain
$userpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "UserPassword1" -AsPlainText -Force #Password for the user account CONTOSO\s-useraccount
$adsearchobj.DomainName = "contoso.com"
$adsearchobj.ShortDomainName = "CONTOSO" #Optional
$adsearchobj.IsForest = $true #$true for Forest, $false for Domain
$adsearchobj.LoginName = "s-useraccount"
$adsearchobj.SetPassword($userpassword)

$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Add($adsearchobj)
$wa.Update()
```

Comment: Thanks This helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

The account in the other domain were locked. After changing the password it worked fine. Used the script Trevor showed above and that works great